# is it possible to send broadcast messages using Twilio whatsapp API

Tags: node.js, twilio, whatsapp

I am trying to integrate Twilio WhatsApp API with my application, is it possible to send broadcast messages using Twilio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can send outbound messages over WhatsApp using Twilio. There are some constraints though.

1. You need to get your users to [explicitly opt in to receive WhatsApp messages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/api#whatsapp-opt-in-requirements)
2. When you send a notification to a user, if it is more than 24 hours since the user sent you a message [you can only send approved template messages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/tutorial/send-whatsapp-notification-messages-templates).
3. [Twilio Notify](https://www.twilio.com/docs/notify) does not support WhatsApp, so to broadcast messages to a group of users you will need to make one API request per message using the [regular Twilio messaging API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/api/message-resource).

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: posting on your point-1, do we need user opt-in for sending approved templates too? I thought, after completing these steps(https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/tutorial/connect-number-business-profile), I can send the preapproved templates to any user without any opt-in.

Comment: It's best to get this from the source, here is what [Facebook says about opt-ins](https://www.whatsapp.com/legal/business-policy/). Specifically: "In order to initiate a WhatsApp message to a person, you must first receive opt-in permission confirming that they wish to receive future messages from you on WhatsApp."